# how to delete previous file in asp.net C# while updating the file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am making a ecommerce web application in asp.net(MVC). when I update the file or image then it was updated but previous were not deleting from the folder. I am using database optimization and store the path of file in database.

I  am trying this code in controller to edit file.

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, [Bind("Id,Name,Image,Description,Status,CreatedBy,CreatedDate,ModifiedBy,ModifiedDate,SeoData,MetaData")] Category category, IFormFile Img)
{
    string FinalPath = "/data/category/pics/" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + Path.GetExtension(Img.FileName);
    using (FileStream FS = new FileStream(_he.WebRootPath + FinalPath, FileMode.Create))
    {
        Img.CopyTo(FS);
    }

    if (id != category.Id)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        try
        {
            category.Image = FinalPath;
            _context.Update(category);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            if (!CategoryExists(category.Id))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
    return View(category);
}
```

Comment: before you update `category.Image`, get the current value of `category.Image` and delete it from the File System.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the piece of code you provided, you are building a new path from a new Guid and writing the file content in the filesystem.
The path update in the database looks correct but it seems like you forgot to delete the file stored at the previous path.
I would retrieve the old path stored in database in the try/catch statement and use it to remove the file from the filesystem. After ensuring the file was successfully deleted, you can proceed with the rest of your workflow.

```
// Retrieve category from db    
string oldPath = _context.Categories.SingleOrDefault(c=>c.Id == id).Image;
// Delete the file and ensure it's gone
File.Delete(oldPath);
if (File.Exists(oldPath))
{
    // Throwing an exception / Notifying error
}
// Updating the entity and saving changes
```

You might want to refactor a bit for null checks and exceptions handling but you should be good to go.

Comment: That helps me a lot. I just have one more issue with it. How could I know that the user edit the file or just his name or anything else. because I want to delete the previous file only when the user edit the file not every time of edit.

Comment: You can check if an entity has changed by checking the State property.

`if (context.Entry(category).State != EntityState.Unchanged)
{
    // Write the new file, delete the old one, update the category
}`